# ¿Que a un boton se le tenga que hacer doble click para se haga el post del form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Todo surge de que un usuario puede que se equivoque al escribir un texto en el input entonces quiero que para que se haga el post de form solo cuando el usuario haga doble click al boton.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos la forma como haces el evento del botón?

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta fue resuelta?

Comment: @A.Cedano Asi es

Comment: ¿Por qué no marcas la respuesta que solucionó tu pregunta? De lo contrario otros usuarios podrían intentar responder inútilmente. Lo mismo para las otras preguntas que tengas abiertas, si tienen solución. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entendido

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar el evento `dblclick()` de jquery de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#id_del_boton").on('dblclick', function(e){

  alert("Hola");

});
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda lo complemente con $("#guardarAprovado").on('dblclick', function(e){
           $("#datoss").submit();

          });

Answer (score 1):

Ademas del evento dblclick es importante cancelar el evento click, una forma de manejarlo podría ser la siguiente:

```js
$("#send").on('click dblclick', function(){
 if (event.type == "click")
  return false

// else
 return confirm("submit form?");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="send">send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

LA respuesta de Fabian Sierra la complemente con

```
$("#guardarAprovado").on('dblclick', function(e){
    $("#datoss").submit();
});
```